# How do I extract a nested JSON object using JSNI Overlay Types in GWT?

Tags: java, json, gwt, jsni

So I have this JSON object coming to me which has roughly the following format:

```
{   "student":{"field1":"","field2":"",....},
    "subjects":[{},{},....,{}]                     }
```

How do I extract the entire contents of "student" and each object in the array of "subjects" in GWT using overlay types and the JsonUtils methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a `JavaScriptObject` that exposes the wrapper object to Java, with getters for the `student` and `subjects` properties as other `JavaScriptObject` and `JsArray`.

```java
final class StudentAndSubjects extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected StudentAndSubjects() { }

  public native Student getStudent() /*-{ return this.student; }-*/;
  public native JsArray<Subject> getSubjects() /*-{ return this.subjects; }-*/;
}

final class Student extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected Student() { }

  public native String getField1() /*-{ return this.field1; }-*/;
  public native String getField2() /*-{ return this.field2; }-*/;
  …
}

final class Subject extends JavaScriptObject {
  protected Subject() { }

  …
}
```

You can then use them like this:

```java
StudentAndSubjects sas = JsonUtils.safeEval(json);
Student student = sas.getStudent();
JsArray<Subject> subjects = sas.getSubjects();
for (int i = 0, l = subjects.length(); i < l; i++) {
  Subject subject = subjects.get(i);
  …
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm quite certain that's what I'm doing. Yet its giving me a 
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal method name "<init>$" in class ... (ie my eqivalent of StudentAndSubjects)

Comment: Aaaaannnnddd some simple debugging sorted that out. There was an issue with some methods not being declared final :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your student is a nested Json object

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject mystudent = obj.getJSONObject("student");
String myfield1 = mystudent.getString("field1");
```

"Subjects" looks like an Array....  for that you can use JSONArray and getJavaScriptObject()
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/json/client/JSONArray.html